# Free tool for creating multi-layered PDF

Tags: gratis, pdf

I'm trying to find any PDF creator/exporter tool, capable of creating multi-layered PDF file. Multi-layering doesn't sound like a really hard to code feature, and thus I don't want to spend a lot of money for such application.

I'm looking for anything that could work as standalone, some open-source office app plugin (I'm aware of some Microsoft Word plugin), GIMP/Inkscape plugin, anything.

For now, the best thing that I've already found is a [command line tool](http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201305/how-to-add-a-new-layer-to-pdf-36526.html).

Additional pros of such software would be also ability of creating some buttons, allowing you to script around your layers.

Any suggestions or unusual ideas really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus):

- freeware / open-source
- cross-platform
- PDF creator (desktop publishing software)
- you can create buttons and forms

It doesn't have layers enabled by default. Go to **File** - **Preferences** - **PDF Export**:

[image]

Here are the properties of a button (it also supports Javascript):

[image]

Comment: Wow, that looks very promising, I will certainly take a closer look on that, thanks :)

Comment: It seems like this is exactly the application that I was looking for, with a lot of useful features and options. I highly recommend it to all of you looking for a lot of PDF creation and manipulation features.